# classification of a dataset with different type features

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, regression, normalization

I would like to do a simple classification on a dataset. Each data, has various attributes such as date time (for example: 2018-01-01 13:03:11), person ID, some binary attributes (which would get values either 0 or 1), some float attributes, some attributes might have NaN, etc.

And for each data, there is label which we want to predict.

I want to use python and simple regression methods. However because attribute types are different, I think I should change them somehow so they will be in the same format, is it right? If yes, could you please help me how should I do that?

For example, my dataset can look like this:

```
> data_number     date              id        yes/no    duration   
> label 0          2018-01-01 15:29:29    1321      0         43.943    
> 0 1          2018-03-01 15:18:09    1334      1         98.007        
> 1 2          2017-01-01 16:29:29    1393      0         431.10        
> 1
```

labels are either 0 or 1.

I appreciate if you also recommend me some web pages that they will explain these kind of problems.

Thank you

Comment: Few points: a) Why regression? this is a classification problem so you need Logistic Regression, SVM, KNN etc. b) you need to divide the data into train/test c) Read basic http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_iris_logistic.html

Answer (score 0):

**Identifying the Problem Type:**

It is important in Machine learning to understand the problem type first. If it is continuous output - [1,23,4,5,6, 5.5, 6.7,..], use Linear Regression. If it is a categorical output - [0,1,0,0,1...] or ['High', 'low', 'Medium', ...] etc., go for Logistic Regression. Since your target labels are either 0 or 1, this is a problem to be worked with Logistic Regression or other Classification algorithms (SVM, Decision Tree, Random Forest).

**Data Cleaning/Exploration:**

You must convert your data to numeric format or standardized format for regression.
https://realpython.com/python-data-cleaning-numpy-pandas/

**Starter Code:**

It seems you are looking for a starter code for your problem. You can find that from Kaggle kernels.  Here are a few links:

- https://www.kaggle.com/juliaelliott/basic-starter-kernel-ncaa-men-s-dataset
- https://www.kaggle.com/sudalairajkumar/xgb-starter-in-python